# NASM x86 - линковщик ругается на обращение к элементам строки

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

Моё задание - ксорить файл 4-байтным ключом.
Вот код:

```
section .bss
    buff resb 4
    fd resb 1
    sum resb 8
    temp resb 1

section .data
    gamma db '#0ja', 0xA
    O_RDONLY equ 0
    O_WRONLY equ 1
    O_RDWR equ 2

section .text:
    global _start

_start:

pop ebx
pop ebx 
pop ebx ;got the name

mov eax, 5
mov ecx, O_RDONLY ;open
mov edx, 0777
int 0x80

mov [fd], eax ;save the desc

loloper:
mov ecx, 4
xor esi, esi

looper: 
push ecx

mov eax, 3
mov ebx, [fd]
mov ecx, buff ;get 1 byte
mov edx, 1
int 0x80

mov bl, 0; if end of file
cmp al, bl
jz exit

mov dl, byte [gamma + si]
mov cl, byte [buff + si]

xor dl, cl

mov byte [buff + si], dl


inc si
pop ecx
loop looper

mov eax, 19
mov ebx, [fd]
mov ecx, -4
mov edx, 1
int 0x80

mov bl, 0
cmp cl, bl
jz loloper

exit:
    mov eax, 6
    mov ebx, [fd]
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80
```

Я делал такое ранее, под DOS, и всё работало, но сейчас, при сборке через

```
nasm -felf32 1.asm
ld -m elf_i386 1.o -o 1
```

мне выдаются ошибки:

```
1.o: In function `looper':
1.asm:(.text:+0x3f): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_16 against `.data'
1.asm:(.text:+0x44): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_16 against `.bss'
1.asm:(.text:+0x4b): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_16 against `.bss'
```

возможно, такое обращение к области памяти недопустимо в 32-битном асм?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> mov dl, byte [gamma + si]
> ```

В x86 нет варианта относительной адресации, когда к 16-битному регистру прибавляется 32-битное смещение (`[reg16 + disp32]`). Есть только `[reg32 + disp8/32]` и `[reg16 + disp8/16]`. Поэтому ассемблер считает, что `[gamma + si]` — это `[reg16 + disp16]` и соответственно резервирует под `gamma` только 2 байта в команде.

Когда позже линкер пытается это слинковать он видит, что адрес этого символа в секции `.data` выходит за границы первого мегабайта и справедливо выдаёт ошибку, что он не помещается в отведённые 16 бит.

---

Собственно здесь и далее надо использовать 32-х битный регистр `esi`:

```
mov dl, byte [gamma + esi]
```

Comment: вау, большое спасибо! 
именно то, что и нужно было узнать